# linear algebra subspaces contained in one another

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

show that if v1 is a subspace of v2 and v2 is a subspace of v3, then v1 is a subspace of v3

Well i can't think of much except maybe saying let cx+y where c is a scalar, be a vector in v1, since cx+y is in v1 it is also in v2 by assumption and since in v2 it also must follow the conditions of v3.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, almost. You should start with 
$\ \ $ Let $x,y\in V_1$ and $c$ a scalar.

Comment: What would be the next step? I honestly don't really see much that is different from the original claim itself.